# Detect New Thread Spawned in .NET

Tags: .net, winforms, multithreading, performance, debugging

I'm trying to implement some performance instrumentation for our Windows Forms app and I'd like to detect when a new thread is spawned (specifically from the UI thread) and watch for when it exits. I know I can catch the thread exit event on

```
System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadExit
```

But I need to find out when a new thread is invoked using the ThreadPool (or BackgroundWorker, which uses the ThreadPool under the hood). Ideally I'd also like to get the StackFrame where it's invoked from.

Anyone know of a way of doing this? WMI perhaps?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a native DLL to your application that triggers required processing on `DLL_THREAD_ATTACH` in [DllMain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682583%28VS.85%29.aspx).

This is the only way to reliably detect all thread creation in a process.

EDIT: This is going to be problematic, because managed threads and native threads do not correspond 1-1.  I think you might have to leverage the managed thread debugging support to do what you want.  Painful but it should work.  For example see [ICorDebugThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms230502.aspx).

> Represents a thread in a process. The
>   lifetime of an ICorDebugThread
>   instance is the same as the lifetime
>   of the thread it represents.

and [ICorDebugProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms232460.aspx) has some useful tools for you.

You don't really want to write a debugger, but you do want this level of inspection for for your managed threads.  The motherlode might be [ICorDebugManagedCallback::CreateThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms231225.aspx).

> Notifies the debugger that a thread
>   has started executing managed code.

There is a corresponding `ExitThread` callback.

Comment: You meant `DLL_THREAD_ATTACH` of course, but `DllMain` is the perfect approach.

Comment: @Ben - I am not so sure about this, see Edit.

Comment: I think that there's no requirement in the standard that CLR threads == Windows kernel threads, but maybe on all known implementations of .NET they do.

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking you might be able to use a [WMI temporary event consumer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393013%28VS.85%29.aspx), with a query like:

```
select * from __InstanceCreationEvent within 3 where
     TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Thread'
```

Then given the thread, you can check the Process Handle and see if it is your app.

Comment: And is there any way you can think of to correlate this the .NET thread object?

Comment: The WITHIN clause is mandatory for event queries which don't have an event provider (an error is raised if it's omitted). The interval is the maximum amount of time in seconds that can elapse before notification of an event must be delivered.

Comment: @JeffN825: It might not even be a .NET thread, in which case there is no associated .NET Thread object.

Answer (score 1):

I would go [this way](https://web.archive.org/web/20150731005946/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/davbr/archive/2007/03/22/enter-leave-tailcall-hooks-part-1-basics.aspx), if I were in your shoes...

> The CLR Profiling API allows you to hook managed functions so that your profiler is called when a function is entered, returns, or exits via tailcall. We refer to these as Enter/Leave/Tailcall hooks, or “ELT” hooks. In this special multi-part investigative series, I will uncover the truth behind ELT. Today I'll write about some of the basics, NGEN, and a word on what we call "slow-path" vs. "fast-path".

Then, try to create method filter, and capture calls to `Thread` constructor.  If it could work, it might be brutal!

Answer (score 0):

This may be at a higher level than you are looking for, but you can use the Windows Performance Monitor to measure several process-related metrics including the number of threads. Just open it from Control Panel | Administrative Tools | Performance. Then choose the "Process" performance object for a list of metrics.

Alternatively, if you are maintaining this application, you could put your own hooks in place to detect when a new thread is started up.

Comment: Indeed we are maintaining it, but I'd like to avoid adding hooks to every location a new thread is spawned where we want tracking (~400k lines of code).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work. I had to put the split('.') in because running in visual studio in debug mode.

```
 var assy = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
 var process = Process.GetProcesses().Where(a => assy.GetName().Name.Contains(a.ProcessName.Split('.')[0]));

        foreach (var p in process)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(p.Threads.Count);
        }
```